# Problem with sub-menu container

Tags: navigation, sub-menu

I try to add container for  of main navigation menu.
This is entire `functions.php` of my custom theme:

```
<?php

function gzabrze_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('glowne',__( 'Menu Główne' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'gzabrze_menu' );

class Child_Wrap extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"custom-sub\"><ul class=\"bg-dark\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Now in my `header.php` i use code below to print main navigation on my site:

```
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'walker'            => new Child_Wrap(),
        'theme_location'    => 'glowne',
        'container'         => 'nav',
        'container_id'      => 'main-menu',
        'menu_class'        => "nav-menu",
        'items_wrap'        => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    ) ); 
?>
```

Problem is that the my `<ul class="sub-menu">` which now should be `<ul class=\"bg-dark\">` instead, is still without container which should appear after use `new Child_Wrap()` from above.

It seems that my theme does not include `Child_Wrap` class from `functions.php` code.

I use Wordpress 4.4.2 .

Comment: Are you sure you've emptied all caches?

Comment: You mean browser cache? If other, how can i do that?

Comment: This is not the source of the problem. I try to use this on other theme, and also not work. Even when i edit `nav-menu-template.php` in `wp-includes` folder, nothing is changing.

Comment: I mean caching plugins like `W3 Super Cache` or similar to.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But i find what was wrong. I delete some plugins (Unyson Framework, Jetpack) and now class take action. When i install this plugins first, and then add class to my `functions.php` nothing was changing. Then in other WP installation i add this class first and plugins second, all wroks fine. When on the first WP installation i just remove plugins above, suddenly all starts works fine.